# Creating an excel formula to calculate returns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have a dataset of monthly stock returns from January 2000 until today for six different stock indices. At the bottom of the page, I want to show the yearly return for each year as a percentage change from the previous year (i.e. I want to create a table with one column having '2001', '2002' and the other column having '8%', '-4%' etc. What command would I use?

I want to calculate the percentage change from december 31st of year n to december 31st of year n+1 for every single year for the stocks in image 1 and place it in the table format of image 2. Is there a command that would let me do this, as well as dragging it down so that it works for all years?
**Dataset**
[image: Dataset]

**Table I want to fill**

[image: Table I want to fill]

Comment: Are you eventually only going to consider 2 values for %change? i.e. say for 2001, value on 31-Dec-2000 and on 31-Dec-2001? So if former is 100 and latter 108 (regardless of the ups and downs in between the year) you should report +8%. Please confirm.

Comment: Hi, yes I will, the 2 values are all I need

Comment: From your snapshot, you do not have Dec 31, 2000 in it, instead it's Dec 29, 2000. Is it  data logging error or  may be Dec 31, 2000 was a holiday or weekend? If these are stock indices, generally stock market does not trade on Public holidays or weekends I guess. If so, how do you want to handle such a situation, in that case may be you should consider last day of the year reported in the sheet?

Comment: Yes sorry, 2000 is the only year that it is dec 29 instead of dec 31st. The last day of the year reported is fine for calculating the percentage change, I just don't know how to type the command

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change Dec 29, 2000 to Dec 31, 2000 so that a relatively simpler formula can be used. As you confirm that you always have Dec 31, YYYY everywhere else. I suggest a formula based on typical INDEX MATCH.

Please see the below screenshot and solution and confirm if this is what you want.
e.g. for year 2000 it's `(Value at Dec 31, 2001 - Value at Dec 31, 2000) / 100`

See sample data, I have skipped a few months in first column to keep it short.
Output table is in H1:K4.

In I2 put the following formula and drag it across and down to fill the table.
Assumption is that the Stock Index names remain in the same sequence as input data, so no specific lookup on them is performed and your First Column in input table is correctly formatted as Date in Excel.

```
=(INDEX(B$2:B$20,MATCH(DATE($H2+1,12,31),$A$2:$A$20,0))-INDEX(B$2:B$20,MATCH(DATE($H2,12,31),$A$2:$A$20,0)))/100
```

Understand where to put $ and where not to, so that single formula can be dragged down and across. Set the cell format of output table as Percentage and 2 decimals. Select the Output table Right Click and Format Cells.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I can confirm that (Value at Dec 31, 2001 - Value at Dec 31, 2000) / 100 for each year is indeed what I would like, so thank you!

Comment: However when I typed the excel command, i got an N/A message for some reason. I am trying to post the screenshot but it doesn't appear that stack exchange will let me?

Comment: N/A could mean somewhere most likely the MATCH function is not finding the items it's looking up. Is the first column properly formatted as DATE?